# Querying SnappyData records from 1000-th to 1010-th

Tags: snappydata

Is there any **pagination** functionality in SnappyData using sql?
For example, there are 10000 records in a table.
Can we do a query to “get 10 entries starting from 1000 to 1010”? 
We need this to support **pagination** feature in our REST API.

Comment: Currently pagination is not supported in SnappyData but will be approximated using an "offset" clause in the next version (1.1)

Comment: You can also try using SCROLL_INSENSITIVE or rank() to achieve something similar

Comment: Thanks this helps